# Android Studio cant run app on emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

My Android Studio can start the emulator but then cant initialise the app. 
At first I start emulator through "Android Virtual Device Manager", then I click on "Run" button and select the "online", already launched and initialised, emulator.

On "messages" tab i receive the following message:

> Error:no devices found

I also tried to start emulator by selecting "Run" button and selecting the emulator I want to start, but the result is the same.

Any ideas on how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that your target sdk version is equal to the version that you are running in the Emulator .and make sure you have unchecked `Tools > Android > Enable ADB Integration`

Comment: still not working. ADB Integration is on, and emulator has Debug mode enabled.